# Prove that the maximal number of linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1 is equal to the number of connected components in $G$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, bipartite-graphs

Let $G$ be a simple graph containing $n$ nodes. Let $V$ be the set of all the nodes and $E$ the set of all edges in $G$.
$$
\text{If } \left\{i, j\right\} \epsilon E, M_{ij} = \frac{1}{\text{deg}(j)}.
\\
\text{Else, } M_{ij} = 0.
$$
Here, $\text{deg}(j)$ denotes the degree of the $j$th node.

1. Prove that the maximal number of linearly independent eigenvectors with eigenvalue 1 is equal to the number of connected components in $G$.
2. Show that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ if and only if $G$ is a bipartite graph.

I have managed to prove the if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$, then $|\lambda| \leq 1$.

Comment: How much do you know about the Laplacian matrix properties?

Comment: @Exodd This is the first time I'm hearing about Laplacian matrices :(

Comment: This is a straight-forward consequence of Perron-Frobenius theory if you have prior knowledge of that